# How filter specific rows in a df

Tags: r, list, dataframe, geometry, row

I want to select each row which have a list values in a geometry column.

Some rows have a empty list and I want to remove them and just get the rows with a list of geometry values...

I can do that with numeric values with `dplyr::filter` but I don't know do that with a list...

Someone can help me please ?

Comment: Can you share an example of your data using `dput`?

Comment: does `df %>% filter(df, lengths(geometry) != 0)` work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your both reply, I put an example more precise in a answer below. @neuron

Comment: @AllanCameron no that's not work, more details in a answer below if you want

Answer (score 0):

Without your data it will be hard to exactly answer your question, and depending on if your list element is `NA`, `NULL`, or length 0 (i.e., `character(0)`, `integer(0)`). A couple of options you could try:

```
# List with both NA and NULL values
lst <- list(c(1:5), c(LETTERS[1:18]), c(NA), c(NULL), integer(), character() ,c(1:17))

# Remove if list element is NULL
plyr::compact(lst)

# Remove if list element is NA
Filter(Negate(anyNA), lst)

# If element is zero length as character(0), integer(0) 
lst[lapply(lst, length) > 0]
```

Comment: Thank for your back but that's seems not work but I put more details in answer below if you want !